# Setting Java Agent = AspectWeaver in Eclipse adds -noverify in the end. How to remove it?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aspectj

I am running trying to test AspectJ to an existing Java application. On the eclipse  `Run > Debug Configuration > Parameter tab > VM Parameters`
I set the following settings.

> -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar

When I press [Debug] I get the following error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to
init: instrument Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing :
lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar-noverify
```

Upon checking the last ran full command option via `Windows > Show View > Others > Debug`, then Right Click properties. I checked the command line and it does show the

```
C:\pleiades\java\8\bin\javaw.exe 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:61420 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=61419 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost 
-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true 
-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar-noverify 
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath
....
```

I am not sure what is adding the -noverify. I tried adding space or newline in the VM parameter settings but it truncate the whitespaces.

> -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar-noverify

I search the "-noverify" in my whole project structure and I saw it being added in the root maven. The project structure I am working with uses parent maven.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-noverify</argLine>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Based on my understanding, it should have no effect. Also, I removed the above plugin and it still adds the -noverify in my agent settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: In _VM Parameters_ adding the line `-Dfoo=0` should give you at least a blank after `-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar`. Maybe a variable _blank_ with a space character as value can be specified and then in VM Parameters used as end line `${blank}`. Regardless of whether this workaround works or not, please report it to Eclipse m2e.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, the `argLine` parameter from Surefire is not added to the Java command line, no matter if I debug an application or a JUnit 4 test with the weaving agent added to the Eclipse (Oxygen 2) debug configuration. Please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to make the problem reproduceable.